# How to use browser validation on a form before submitting via Ajax?

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, browser

Using an HTML5 form with new type (email, url, etc), I have binded the submit event with a JS function.

The problem is that the browser first call this function, and then call its validation system, but **only if the submit function hasn't returned false**.

Or, I do the Ajax request and all the work in that function, meaning I always return false.

How could I enable the browser validation to be executed before the call of the submit js function ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From specification the browser should first validate the form and then, if the form is valid should trigger a submit event. This means, that you simply should be able to do your Ajax submit inside the submit event.

Currently Opera does first fire the submit event and then does the validation. You can simply call manually the validation inside of your submit listener, using checkValidity-method:

```
$(form).bind('submit', function(){
    if(!this.checkValidity || this.checkValidity()){
        //do ajax and return false
    }
});
```

Note: that this can doubble the invalid events in those browsers, too. If you don't use them, evrything should be fine. If you want to use them and don't want them doubbled you can use [webshims lib](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/demos/webforms.html), which fixes this and other issues in different browsers.

Comment: Nice. Now how to trigger the browser saying what field is invalid and why like when submitting without ajax? MDN docs says ´checkValidity´does that, but not for me..Since my ajax events trigger on all kind of events and not just the submit, I have to manually do this somehow..

Comment: I just answered my own comment question here. So, if you cannot  do your ajax code on the form field, here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53922759/301753